# As root, how can I list the crontabs for all users?

Tags: cron

I have a script being run automatically that I can't find in the crontab for the expected users, so I'd like to search all users' crontabs for it.

Essentially I want to run a `crontab -l` for all users.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Well depends on the script but easily you can find your crontab as root with

```
crontab -l -u <user>
```

Or you can find crontab from spool where is located file for all users

```
cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/<user>
```

To show all users' crontabs with the username printed at the beginning of each line:

```
cd /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ && grep . *
```

Comment: Awesome, looking in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ worked nicely, thanks!

Comment: `crontab -e -u <user>` to edit it works as well

Comment: `/var/spool/cron/<user>` on my Centos 7 host.

Answer (score 24):

One liner which lists all users and prints cron for every user:

```
for user in $(getent passwd | cut -f1 -d: ); do echo $user; crontab -u $user -l; done
```

This solution:

- Doesn't require knowing a system specific crontab path (e.g. `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` vs `/var/spool/cron/`
- Won't list "orphan" crons, i.e. crons for users that don't exist anymore (and thus are not executed effectively)

Comment: Note: this works for `sh` but not `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for USER in `cat /etc/passwd | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'`
do
  echo "this crontab for user : $USER"
  crontab -u $USER -l 2>&1
done >> list_all_cron
```

Strange need to escape chars on this web site. I think copy paste won't work

Well you got the point : loop all users from `/etc/passwd` + `awk` and ask for `crontab` with `crontab -u -l`

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Indeed the backtick is used for in-line comment formatting, making it difficult to use. Still, please note that the backtick format is [deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated) anyway for command substitutions, and the `$( ... )` format should be used instead. Also, you don't really need to `cat` a file into  `awk`, just give the file to be read as parameter after the command.

Answer (score 1):

To filter out comments from only active user crontabs:

```
for user in $(getent passwd | cut -f1 -d: ); do echo $user; crontab -u $user -l | grep -v "^#"; done
```

or quick and dirty from both common directories:

```
grep -v "^#" /var/spool/cron/crontabs/* /var/spool/cron/*
```

Comment: Sorry, just tried these out in ubuntu. First one you need to be root first (`sudo -i`) (you can prob modify the one liner to run the crontab commmand as root). I generally don't like been in a shell as root so I haven't tried this as root to see if it even works,

Second one also needs to be run as sudo, so you may want to add that in

Comment: While I agree, one should use sudo instead of logging in as root, the question posted starts with 'as root', and all other answers up to this point have assumed root, so I continued that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

In RHEL/OEL you can list the cron jobs created by all users:

```
#cd /var/spool/cron/
#ls -1
root
oracle
user1
```

To see root's cronjobs:

```
#cat root
```

Comment: The crontab(1) interface (command) should be used, as it protects against concurrent editing of the crontab database.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following command, we findall Cron jobs, on the specified system.

```
find /etc/cron* -type f -perm -o+w -exec ls -l {} \;
```