# Alter another user's crontab tasks

Tags: cron, root

Similar to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119602/165107), I would like to alter a user's crontab file as root. I'm able to view the crons, but unable to alter or edit them. To view them, I use the following:

```
sudo crontab -l -u <user>
```

Comment: If you have root you could always `sudo su <user>` and use `cron` normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To alter a user's crontab with root privileges, run the following command:

```
sudo crontab -u <user> -e
```