# Will adding a user in cron.deny kill the running job for that user?

Tags: linux, cron

suppose user tom is having bunch of scheduled jobs and if add this user in cron.deny. Will this kill any running jobs for that user ?

I know it will deny to schedule jobs but will it stop the running jobs as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a user to `cron.deny` will not stop/kill the running job for that user. Adding a user to `cron.deny` will only blocks that user from being able to use `crontab` command only.

from `man crontab`:

> If the /etc/cron.allow file exists, then you must be listed (one user
> per line) therein in order to be allowed to use
> this command.  If the /etc/cron.allow file does not exist but the /etc/cron.deny file does exist, then you  must  not
> be listed in the /etc/cron.deny file in order to use this command.

*`this command`* meaning at above is refer to `crontab` command itself.

Comment: Which brings up an interesting situation. If a user has existing crontab entries and is then added to `cron.deny`, the existing entries will continue to be run and cannot be deleted by the user.

Comment: @doneal24 usually user do not block itself, [that's most probably a sysadmin that can also delete them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119598/72456)